# Are dynamic and external React components possible in runtime?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, code-splitting

We're developing a dashboard React-application in which other (trusted) developers can create their own React-widgets in separate environments. The goal would be a situation where new widgets wouldn't require updation to the dashboard-application and instead, these external React-components could be loaded **at runtime**.

So developer `A` would have his own project, where he would bundle a React-component into a js-file, which would be forwarded to a hosting site, S3 for example where the dashboard application could read them via a string, at runtime.

For example a weather-widget:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function Weather() {
    const [city, setCity] = useState("city");
    const weatherUri = `https://wttr.in/${city}_tqp0.png`;
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={city} onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}/>
            <div>
                <img src={weatherUri} alt={city}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Weather;
```

This could be then imported to the dashboard-application. I've understood that React's dynamic code-splitting with dynamic url would work here. Either via a situation where widget would have its own React-library, or it'd get it from the dashboard-application. We've, in fact, made this to work, but as soon as we add a state to the component, it breaks:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at Object.useState (react.development.js:1612:23)
    at Weather (weather_widget.js:36:33)
```

We've configured the widget-component's configuration as follows (React-library will be imported from the dashboard-application):

```
// ====== vite.config.js ========== (widget)
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/lib/Weather.tsx',
      name: 'Weather',
      fileName: 'weather',
      formats: ['es']
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
          externalGlobals({
            react: "React"
          })
      ],
      external: ['react'],
      output: {
        globals:{
          react: 'React'
        }
      }
    }
  },
})

// ===== package.json ===== (widget)
{
  "name": "weather",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-external-globals": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.7.23",
    "@types/react": "18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "vite": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

This is how we've tried to import it to the dashboard-application:

```
export const WidgetCard = (widgetId: string) => {

    const WidgetComponent = React.lazy(() =>
            import(`/path/to/${widgetId}.js`));

    return 
      <>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>
          <WidgetComponent/>
        </Suspense>
      </>
    )
});
```

For the final product, the logic would be as follows:

1. User will generate a JS-bundle of their React-component
2. User will call some sort of API, which will save bundle to a hosting site and also add the new widget to a database of some sort.

Comment: Have you actually set React on the global in the consumer app? That rollup plugin `externalGlobals` is expecting it to be available on the global.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, like in some root index, try `window.React = React`

Comment: BTW what you are trying to do is quite close to the idea of "microfrontends" . This might be useful when researching around this.

Comment: Well, after we did the rollup-plugin configuration on the widget, we'd get an error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined at weather_widget.js:4:23`

We fixed this error by applying React and React DOM in dashboard's `index.html`:
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>`

After that, we got the current error.

We haven't actually included the `window.React = React` anywhere.